# How to download data directory from www directory of shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to provide a link to the user to download a list of test data files stored in WWW directory of my shiny app. I tried something displayed below.

```
library(shiny)

    # server.R
    server <- function(input, output) {

      output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
        filename = 'data',
        content = function(fname) {
           testdata
        })

    }

    # ui.R
    ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
      titlePanel('Downloading Data'),
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          downloadLink ('downloadData', 'Download')
        ),
        mainPanel()
      )
    )
    )

    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However, it does not work. How to do.

Answer (score 1):

There is main question how you read data? how you get `testdata`?

for example if you have `data.csv` in your `www`

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  testdata=read.csv2('www\\data.csv',header = F)

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename =function() { 'data.csv'},

    content = function(file){
      fname <- paste(file,"csv",sep=".")
      write.csv2(testdata,fname)
      file.rename(fname,file)
    }

   )

})
```

for me work only in browser

You can also try to create zip of all files( cant test zip not work on my R)

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  wd=getwd()
  testdata=c("data.csv","data1.csv")
  testdata_full_path=path.expand(paste0(wd,"\\www\\",testdata))

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = 'data.zip',
    content = function(fname) {
      tmpdir <- tempdir()
     lapply(testdata_full_path,function(i) file.copy(i,tmpdir))
      setwd(tmpdir)
      zip('data.zip',files= testdata)
      setwd(wd)
     unlink(tmpdir)

    },
    contentType = "application/zip"
  )



})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As i mentioned , i have a list of files in a directory with name `testdata` within the www directory. How it works to download the full directory.

Comment: Warning in `file.copy(i, tmpdir) :
  problem copying G:\Meta-Analysis\Rshinny\meta-analysis methods\meta-analysis methods\data.csv to C:\Users\Hussain\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpAZjwCC\data.csv: No such file or directory
Warning in file.copy(i, tmpdir) :
  problem copying G:\Meta-Analysis\Rshinny\meta-analysis methods\meta-analysis methods\data1.csv to C:\Users\Hussain\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpAZjwCC\data1.csv: No such file or directory
Warning: running command '"/usr/bin/zip" -r9X "data.zip" "data.csv" "data1.csv" ' had status 127
Error opening file: 2
Error reading: 6`

Comment: i forget `www` in file path. and you need to have `data.csv` and `data1.csv` in your `www` forlder

Comment: Now this : `Warning: running command '"/usr/bin/zip" -r9X "data.zip" "data.csv" "data1.csv" ' had status 127
Error opening file: 2
Error reading: 6`

Comment: I also have same promble .... because zip not work in my R .. can you use zip without shiny?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort.  I have to use zip with shiny app only. There may be any solution.